# How to make jQuery constructor properties globally visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, constructor, this

I am trying to get position coordinate variables using the standard Navigator.geolocation property with jquery, so i can use the value later in my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.getlocation = function(){
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition($.getPosition,$.error);
    }

    $.getVariables = function(lat,lon){
          this.lat = lat; // i want these to be visible
          this.lon = lon;
    }

    $.getPosition= function(position){
          console.log("latitude:" +position.coords.latitude+ " longitude: "+position.coords.longitude);
          //this function will be executed once position is determined.


    $.getVariables(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
    }

    $.error = function(){alert("error");}

    $.getlocation(); // outputs correctly

    setTimeout(()=>{console.log(this.lat)},5000); // undefined

});
```

I expect to get location output but instead i get `undefined` from `console.log(this.lat)`, i did try this in vanilla javascript and it works fine, here is the javascript code:

```
function locateMe() {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosition, error);
    } else {

        alert("connection problem");
    }
}

let vars = function(lat, lon) {
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lon = lon;
}

let getPosition = function(position) {
    vars(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.loongitude);
}


let error = function(msg) {
    console.log("problem");
}

locateMe();

setTimeout(() => { console.log(this.lat); }, 5000); //correct output
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get `this.lat` working if I changed `getVariables` to:

```
$.getVariables = function(lat,lon){
    document.lat = lat;
    document.lon = lon;
}
```

It appears that the two `this` objects may refer to different things in the two methods.